# Conditional rendering with && operator within react return statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I structure my return statement in a class component when my condition is using && operator as in:

```
if (x === null && y === null)
```

...then show this html:

```
<div className="col-12">
    <SomeComponent />
</div>
```

else show this html:

```
   <div className="col-6">
        <SomeOtherComponent />
   </div>
   <div className="col-6">
        <SomeOtherComponent />
   </div>
```

I need this to be inside the return statement because I am wrapping the entire condition in a `<main><div className="row></div></main>` wrapper as in:

```
<main>
  <div className="row">
    // show the above mentioned html conditionally
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the short hand if statement `<condition> ? <if true> : <if false>`. Your return statement should look like this.

```
 return (
    <main>
      {x === null && y === null ? (
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-12">
            <SomeComponent />
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-6">
            <SomeOtherComponent />
          </div>
          <div className="col-6">
            <SomeOtherComponent />
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </main>
  );
```

[codesandbox with working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/v0jk200zkl)

Answer (score 1):

here is how you do it use ternary operator: `{condition ? (if condition is  true ) : (if condition is false)}`

```
    <main>
      <div className="row">
          {x === null && y === null ? (
<div className="col-12">
    <SomeComponent />
</div>):  (<div className="col-6">
        <SomeOtherComponent />
   </div>
   <div className="col-6">
        <SomeOtherComponent />
   </div>)}
     </div>
    </main>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ternary operator:

```
(x === null && y === null) ? (render if true) : (render this if false)
```

Also, null is falsy value so you can write `(!x && !y)`.

If you want to write with ifs, call method like `this.renderComponent()` and resolve everything there and just return value or whole component.